# .NET 5 reference from a .NET Framework Oracle 9i Data Access

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-5, .net-framework-version, oracle9i

I am developing a small web application that needs to reference an existing .NET Framework(4.6) class library. This library is from an old project which connects to an Oracle 9i database for the data access.

Since Oracle 9i is not supported by ODP.NET, is it possible to reference the .net framework class library in the .net 5 project?

Comment: netcore cannot ref .netframework libs.

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. You can't mix the two different runtimes. If ODP.NET can't connect to that 21 year old database you'll have to find (probably buy) a driver that can

Comment: The .net framework library is using System.Data.OracleClient dll to connect to the database.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can't mix .NET Core and .NET Framework assemblies. .NET Core is cross-platform while .NET Framework drivers only work on Windows. Even if .NET Core had an Oracle driver it *wouldn't* support a 20+ year old database. In any case, ODP.NET was probably the worst possible driver back in the 2000s. Other third party drivers were far smaller and faster, eg Devart's drivers.

Comment: Another possibility is to install the ODBC drivers (if they still work) and use OdbcConnection instead of OracleConnection

Comment: Surely it would be easier to upgrade the db? Or even export it to another RDBMS

Comment: @CaiusJard it's Oracle. And a 20 yo database at that. It's *very* expensive and there's no way to easily migrate from 9i to 19c directly. They'd have to migrate through intermediate versions or recreate the schema and copy the data from the old to the new one - assuming they could find a tool that could connect to 9i. That would be a major project any way you look at it

Comment: Indeed, hence the "export to another db" bit; if one is going to jump those hoops, then a dump and pump into something else might be preferable

Comment: @CaiusJard procrastination in this case has turned technical debt to a very real cash debt. At this point, migrating to MySQL 8 Enterprisewould be cheaper overall - Oracle 9i wasn't very easy to manage and technology-wise, MySQL 8 Enterprise is pretty close to Oracle

Comment: If nothing else, and given that you seem to be saying you do have code already that will connect and work with this database, fronting it into eg a webservice using the framework side and and calling the service using the core side would bridge your core app to the db, though it would be less performant. Something has to give.. Fast, cheap, good. Pick 2

Comment: @CaiusJard upgrading at the moment will not be possible due to specific reasons and other reasons (one is the big jump from 9i to 19c). Will try ODBC if possible

Comment: @onhax the upgrade moment passed at least 10 years ago. It will only get worse the longer you wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using the System.Data.OracleClient namespace and ported all the needed data access related methods from the old .net framework library to the .net5 project. I had to set the platform target to `x86`, since `Any CPU` will not work due to compatibility reasons.

Also adding a reminder that Oracle 9i(not sure with newer versions) returns integers as decimals (`1` to `1.0`) throwing an error when converting `OracleDataReader` to typed classes.

Answer (score 1):

The ODP.NET assembly needs and Oracle (Instant) Client, their versions have to match exactly!

According [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1) you need Oracle Client version 11.2 or older - if "Oracle 9i" means version 9.2.0.

[image]

You can still download ODAC version 11.2 from [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)](https://www.oracle.com/ch-de/database/technologies/dotnet-utilsoft-downloads.html) and [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)](https://www.oracle.com/ch-de/database/technologies/odac-downloads.html)

But I guess, you need to compile at .NET Framework version 4.x

Comment: That won't work with .NET Core.  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core only works with Oracle 12c or later.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not talking about Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core. `Oracle.DataAccess` (no "Managed" and no "Core") works with .NET Framework(4.6) as given in the question.

Comment: The question is about .NET 5, not .NET Framework. The OP is trying to use a library that targets .NET Framework 4.6. The OP can already connect to Oracle 9i in .NET Framework. The problem is that the library now has to be used in .NET Core, so ODP.NET can't be used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh yes, you are right. I will keep my answer anyway for reference.